# C struct/union with explicit (manual) field layout?

Tags: c#, c, visual-c++

What is the C equivalent of this C# code?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Test
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] int a;  // Integer at byte offset 0
    [FieldOffset(1)] int b;  // Integer at byte offset 1
    [FieldOffset(3)] int c;  // Integer at byte offset 3
};
```

<sub>(I don't care if it's non-portable, e.g. `int` is assumed to be 4 bytes, etc.)</sub>

Comment: I would have thought that even if they are overlapping fields, they should still be aligned properly.  Is that actually valid on any platform?

Comment: @Jeff: AFAIK x86 doesn't care. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548164/mis-aligned-pointers-on-x86/548411#548411)

Comment: It's one thing for a pointer, but it's another for struct members AFAIK.

Comment: @Jeff: It's completely fine, the compiler can do unaligned read magic if necessary. [Take a look at `bpb33` here](http://seas.ucla.edu/~mkampe/cs111.wq11/docs/freebsd/bpb_h.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine under Visual Studio:

```
#pragma pack(push)

#pragma pack(1)
typedef union
{
    int a;
    struct
    {
        char unused0;
        int b;
    };
    struct
    {
        char unused1;
        char unused2;
        char unused3;
        int c;
    };
} Test;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: But apparently you're not satisfied with either of those particular solutions.  This on the other hand should meet your expectations right?  Direct access to the `int` members aligned as specified.  What else would you expect?

Comment: Jeff, I think the question has not been posed precisely.  You and I both assumed he was asking how to build a C data structure with explicit layout, and apparently that is not the case.

Comment: @Jeff: My apologies -- I didn't notice that your structs are anonymous, and that the fields are directly accessible. It's less than ideal but definitely a usable answer and different from the others, +1; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro that should work across clang, gcc and msvc (haven't tested the msvc version):

```c
#define YDUMMY(suffix, size) char dummy##suffix[size]
#define XDUMMY(suffix, size) YDUMMY(suffix, size)
#define DUMMY(size) XDUMMY(__COUNTER__, size)
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define EXPLICIT_UNION_START(name) union Test {
#define EXPLICIT_UNION_END() };
#define EXPLICIT_OFFSET_FIELD(foff, ftype, fname) struct __attribute__((packed)) { DUMMY(foff); ftype fname; };
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define EXPLICIT_UNION_START(name) #pragma pack(push, 1) \
union Test {
#define EXPLICIT_UNION_END() }; \
#pragma pack(pop)
#define EXPLICIT_OFFSET_FIELD(foff, ftype, fname) struct { DUMMY(foff); ftype fname; };
#else
#error "What compiler is this?"
#endif

EXPLICIT_UNION_START(Test)
    EXPLICIT_OFFSET_FIELD(0, int, a)
    EXPLICIT_OFFSET_FIELD(1, int, b)
    EXPLICIT_OFFSET_FIELD(3, int, c)
EXPLICIT_UNION_END()
```

Thanks to unnamed fields, the syntax to access your defined fields is not polluted by dummy names:

```c
int main() {
    union Test t;
    t.b = 13;
    printf("offset a = %zx\n", offsetof(union Test, a));
    printf("offset b = %zx\n", offsetof(union Test, b));
    printf("offset c = %zx\n", offsetof(union Test, c));
    printf("t.b = %d\n", t.b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
union u_t {
    struct {
        int V;
    } a;
    struct {
        byte dummy;
        int V;
    } b;
    struct {
        byte dummy1;
        byte dummy2;
        byte dummy3;
        int V;
    } c;
};
```

The dummy fields are used to force offsets.  I think some compilers can force field or struct alignment, so you need to insure when you compile, that option is off. See the [pragma pack directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Default_packing_and_.23pragma_pack). The way to get to the  a, b, c values is to reference the V field within each respective struct in the union.  Eg if u is of type u_t, then

```
  u.c.V = 17;
```

Comment: That doesn't work because then I can't read/write `c` as though it were an integer.

Comment: Well then change the names to struct1 struct2 struct3. As I said in my answer originally, you reference the `c` value with `u.c.V`.  V is an integer.  If you are concerned about the symbol names, change them.

Comment: So what I'm understanding is "there's no direct translation for this in Visual C++" -- is that correct?

Comment: Well I don't understand the question.  When I read "what's the equivalent", I thought you were looking for a data structure that had similar layout, which would allow you to reference different 4-byte int values pointing into the same blob of memory, at different offsets.  The C Union is the thing that does this, and the union I suggested does that. You seem to also have this idea that you want *exactly the same syntax as well as semantics*.  And I don't think there is an answer to that. C has different syntax. You've overconstrained the problem. You need to decide what you really want.

Comment: Maybe what you are asking is, how do I do this in C++ with the managed extensions?  and in that case, it's basically the same syntax.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5375370/48082

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a union, perhaps with some #defines to simplify the usage.

```
union Test {
    struct {
        int V_a;
    } s_a;
    struct {
        char V_a;
        int V_b;
    } S_b;
    struct {
        char V_a;
        short V_b;
        int V_c;
    } S_c;

#define a S_a.V_a
#define b S_b.V_b
#define c S_c.V_c
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you should be able achieve similar effect using [bit fields](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html).

Also, for Visual C++, it might be worth looking at: `__declspec(align(#))` or `#pragma pack`.

Comment: Would bit fields treat the integers as 4 bytes or 1 byte?

Comment: @Mehrdad They will be treated as wide as they were declared. For example if you have an `unsigned int x : 3`, and try to assign 8 to it, the field will actually become 0 because of the wrap-around (3 bits can represent numbers from 0 to 7). There is nothing, however, stopping you from declaring fields as `: 8` or `: 32` bits wide (for 1 and 4 bytes respectively). You can also wrap bit fields in unions, or manipulate them at the bit level, so you can implement pretty much any behavior imaginable...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to using the union is to instead use methods to access the values, as you probably should be doing anyway. Although it's C++, where you asked for C - but I'm assuming C++ is fine based on your use of VC++.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
struct Test {
    int a() {
        return *(int*)&values_[0];
    }
    void a(int value) {
        *(int*)&values_[1] = value;
    }
    int b() {
        return *(int*)&values_[1];
    }
    void b(int value) {
        *(int*)&values_[1] = value;
    }
    int c() {
        return *(int*)&values_[3];
    }
    void c(int value) {
        *(int*)&values_[3] = value;
    }

private:
    char[8] values_;
};
#endif
```

Comment: I never fully understood the subject but doesn't this violate strict aliasing rules?

Comment: It does, but unimportant for the topic of the question, since he wasn't concerned about portability etc. If you wanted it to be a bit cleaner, you'd replace those dereferences with bit shifting operators to set each byte individually, (at the cost of performance, though, probably negligible.)